# change opacity on radio button checked

Tags: css, radio-button, checked

I have this html:

```
<label class="fakeRadio active">
   <input type="radio">
</label>
```

this is my css:

```
.fakeRadio input[type=radio]:checked  + .fakeRadio.active {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

for some reason the fakeRadio active class don't get the opacity,any idea why?

Comment: ok,so the solution is only javascript?

Comment: Musa - any solution ?

Comment: just use comma `,` instead of `+` and it will work just fine.

Comment: `.fakeRadio input[type=radio]` is the same as `.fakeRadio.active`, it's selecting the same element. [Remove just the second selector](http://jsfiddle.net/8m9Yd/).

Comment: Mostafa Adly - ok,this working,but now both of them get the opacity,how can I made that only the parent label will get the opacity? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to

```
.fakeRadio input[type=radio]:checked, .fakeRadio.active {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/mwNFD/

If you want to change the label ony then do this

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/mwNFD/

```
<input type="radio">
<label class="fakeRadio active">
   Label text
</label>



input[type="radio"]:checked +label {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use CSS level 4 and the parent selector

read more here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/

```
E! > F  an E element parent of an F element
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

better use this

```
  <input id=myInput type="radio">
  <label for="myInput" class="fakeRadio active"> </label>
```

the css:

```
.fakeRadio input[type=radio] + label[for=myInput] {
        margin-left:-4px;
    }

.fakeRadio input[type=radio]:checked + label[for=myInput] {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: And only a few lines up from the entry you link to, at the W3C, the *same document* clearly says that the subject-selector won't be available in CSS 4 (as currently written): http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#profiles